# Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler'

Tags: .net-6.0

nAn error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DefaultInterp. I cannot add migration. Note I have updated my project to be on .Net 6

I Tried to include  CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); from Program.cs file into my pipeline Startup class. i still have public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) even though it is .net 6 which is confusing

Comment: Can you please share your .csproj files?